# msbuild arguments failing for new website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, msbuild

I am facing a problem with msbuild that I have not been able to solve.

About 15 month ago I inherited an asp.net mvc web solution containing about 6 websites.  For about a year I have been building all of these sites using the azure build pipelines and deploying them with azure deployment pipelines.

We have been using these msbuild arguments to build all of the sites in the solution.

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PublishBaseUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
```

This always worked just fine and produces a very clean folder structure which we  can deploy easily.

However, I have recently added a 7th site to the solution and upon doing so i now receive the following error when trying to build with these arguments.

```
C:\source\myproject.csproj" (default target) (17) ->
(WebFileSystemPublish target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSyst
em.targets(55,5): error : This specific WebPublishMethod(FileSystem) is not yet supported on msbuild command line.  Please use Visual Studio to publish.

error : Target WebFileSystemPublish Failed
```

The error only occurs on the brand new project just added to the solution.  I have tried to locate a setting in the project file that may be causing this but I havent come up with anything at this time.

update:
Analyzing the msbuild logs shows the following error occuring only on the new csproj file added to the solution indicating an issue with "default target"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not sure what caused the error above with msbuild.  The primary change we are aware of is a modificaiton from the .net framework 4.5 to 4.7.2

The resolution to this issue after a lot of work and research was to use the following msbuild arguments in azure devops:

/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishbaseurl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:DeployOnbuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish

and adding this file into every project folder in our solution.
'directory.build.props'

with the following xml inside

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl Condition="'$(PublishBaseUrl)' != '' and '$(PublishUrl)' == ''">$(PublishBaseUrl)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</PublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This instantly allowed our builds to begin succeeding creating one folder for each project in the solution.

Comment: Hi @Matt, Thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.